# is there a way to schedule mysql events on mysql 5.0 and older?

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

I hope you can help me very quickly. Is there a way how I can schedule events in mysql 5.0?

In Version 5.1 and newer you can do something like this

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1; 
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS "event_name" 
ON SCHEDULE AT 'datetime' DO UPDATE "tablename" 
SET "column" = 'value' WHERE id = "id"
```

Are there a solution for older versions?

I know that I can update the system. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3):

Event schedulers were introduced from MySQL 5.1 onwards. For older version you have to use the schedulers of your OS like `cron` in Unix or `WindowsScheduler` to schedule an event in MySQL.